# How to Use ISynchronizeInvoke interface?

Tags: c#

What is the working procedure of `ISynchronizeInvoke`?

How to work with it in C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This basically describes a way to push work between threads; to push an item of work onto the other thread, use either `Invoke` (synchronous) or `BeginInvoke` (asynchronous - ideally calling `EndInvoke` later). Likewise, `InvokeRequired` is used to ask "do I need to do this? or can I execute the work myself?".

The most common use of this interface is in windows-forms, where it is part of how to push work onto the UI thread; you can of course use `Control.Invoke` / `Control.BeginInvoke` equally, but forms controls implement this interface to allow abstraction - so downstream code doesn't need to tie itself to windows forms. In the case of forms, `InvokeRequired` means "am I the UI thread?".

In reality, I'm not sure it is that common to use it directly. It is more common to handle events on the UI, and have the UI handle thread-switching using the most appropriate local mechanism.

Typical usage:

```
obj.Invoke((MethodInvoker) SomeMethod);
```

which executes (via a delegate) `SomeMethod` on the thread managed by `obj` (which implements the interface).

Comment: I have recently viewed a very easy implementation of `ISynchronizeInvoke` accompanied by a very simple `IAsyncResult` implementation: http://gurkashi.blogspot.com/2011/01/hi-all-in-this-post-i-will-demonstrate.html. Not to hi-jack the question, but I'm wondering if, now, with .Net 4.5 I can use async/await instead of the old-school pattern of BeginInvoke with callbacks. Even though the interface says `BeginInvoke`, *under the hood* I can implement from my 4.5 toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

[ISynchronizeInvoke Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx)

> The ISynchronizeInvoke interface
>   provides synchronous and asynchronous
>   communication between objects about
>   the occurrence of an event. Objects
>   that implement this interface can
>   receive notification that an event has
>   occurred, and they can respond to
>   queries about the event. In this way,
>   clients can ensure that one request
>   has been processed before they submit
>   a subsequent request that depends on
>   completion of the first.

Also refer

http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/01/07/isynchronizeinvoke-now.aspx

Comment: Yap..i think this can be used to update UI in main thread using the Background Thread of lower tier logic?