# ISynchronizeInvoke missing in System.ComponentModel

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to implement `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface in UWP app. Even with `using System.ComponentModel;` it says type or namespace `ISynchronizeInvoke` could not found.

Does anyone know how to implement `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface in UWP app. I am building iOT App.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Use [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) instead, basically. That's the more modern replacement for `ISynchronizeInvoke`.

Comment: I am working with USB FingerPrint (Suprema) SDK. To initialize 

`public UFScannerManager(

ISynchronizeInvoke synInvoke

);

method to be called. So I can't change `ISynchronizeInvoke' to  'synchronizationcontext'

Comment: @Chitta: Well does that SDK support UWP apps? (And how were we meant to know that from your question?)

Comment: you are correct,I will check with the supplier. Thanks.